# How many degrees of freedom do the estimators of a panel regression have?

Tags: regression, inference, panel-data, degrees-of-freedom, t-distribution

I have multiple observations for multiple people stored in a panel.

Here's a sample of my data (where `id` is a unique person identifier and `year` is the period of observation):

```py
                    y  constant        x1         x2
   id year                                          
01001 2015  -7.849364         1  0.000000   7.108348
      2016  -7.323271         1  0.000000  14.216696
      2017  -7.278819         1  0.476695  21.325043
      2018  -7.505592         1  0.953390  28.433391
01002 2015 -11.512925         1  0.000000   6.422342
      2016 -11.512925         1  0.000000  12.844685
      2017 -11.512925         1  0.066752  19.267027
      2018 -10.819778         1  0.133505  25.689369
```

Suppose I observed 100 people for four periods each. If I were to run the following model

$Y_{i,t} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_{1,i} + \beta_2 X_{2,i} + u_{i,t}$

how many degrees of freedom would the t-distributions for the parameters have? Would using clustered standard errors affect this?